# Devemos priorizar algoritmos humanamente legíveis para estudantes?

Tags: debate, respostas

Quando ensinamos algoritmos para novos programadores, tentamos mostrar de forma simples o que um procedimento, função, etc. de fato, é, e para isso tentamos ser o mais "simples" possível. É notório que programadores experientes usem algoritmos "pouco humanamente legíveis", pois já estão acostumados com a sintaxe.

Por exemplo, ao ensinarmos para um estudante sobre um condicional, tentamos usar uma sintaxe breve e simples:

```c
if (numero > 10) {
    faça_alguma_coisa()
} else {
    faça_outra_coisa()
}
```

Mas é comum vermos programadores experientes tendo o mesmo resultado acima com:

```c
numero > 10 ? faça_alguma_coisa() : faça_outra_coisa()
```

Outro exemplo prático: este usuário preferiu escrever [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/361245/24529) de forma "longa", mas intuitiva:

```
TxtCgc.Text = numcgc.Substring(0, 3) + "." + numcgc.Substring(3, 3) + "." + numcgc.Substring(6, 3) + "-" + numcgc.Substring(9, 2)
```

Sendo que é possível:

```
TxtCgc.Text = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}", numcgc.Substring(0, 3), numcgc.Substring(3, 3), numcgc.Substring(6, 3), numcgc.Substring(9, 2))
```

Ou até mesmo:

```
TxtCgc.Text = Long.Parse(numcgc).ToString("000\.000\.000-00")
```

Isso acontece em outras situações, como uso de operadores, escrita de informação dentre outras milhares de situações que "encurtamos" o código.

Levando em consideração o código limpo, um código curto também pode ser eficiente da mesma forma que um código longo. Mas para estudantes, qual método devemos usar?

Comment: Cada um faz como acha melhor em cada contexto. E será julgado pela comunidade por isso. O ideal é só não ter erro, que tenha explicação das escolhas, mas não que seja absolutamente obrigatório. Mostre o que acha melhor para a pessoa aprender. Mostrar um mecanismo é uma coisa, mostrar como a pessoa deve fazer em uso real é outra. Quer ensinar o erro? Ainda que não seja um erro de fato, apenas uma forma não tão boa. Quase sempre eu faço como eu faria, em poucos casos eu adapto.

Comment: O importante, no meu ver, é deixar claro o contexto. O espaço da resposta é suficiente para ir direto ao ponto no começo, e elaborar depois (ou o contrário, passar a teoria e fechar com um código "real"). E cada um tem seu jeito de fazer, o importante é não vender "gato por lebre". Vale notar que em alguns contextos `numero > 10 ? faça_alguma_coisa() : faça_outra_coisa()` é pior que o if else separado. Código "encurtado na marra" não significa código bom, depende do caso. (exemplo, uso do `map` onde `for` resolve de maneira mais eficiente, erro comum de quem não tem domínio do funcionamento).

Comment: _"encurtado na marra"_...nossa! Nem me fale. E quando eu encontro horrores (nos code review) "encurtados" como ternário dentro de ternário dentro de ternário... sendo que uns `if` s deixaria tudo tão mais legível e organizado.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, dá para aninhar alguns condicionais ternários mantendo-se [legível e manutenível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/499720/137387). Mas eu entendo do que está dizendo, tem pessoas que caem no engodo de exibir com um código exotérico achando que parecerão mais inteligentes.

Comment: Só dizer que não votei nem +1 e nem -1, não por descaso. A pergunta me foi boa como indivíduo para refletir como estou me expressando. Mas concordo com os colegas que o contexto é quem vai definir a ênfase e o detalhamento que serão atribuídos a uma linha ou fragmento de código, e por isso o não voto(concordo e não concordo, depende do contexto).

Comment: Considerando o objetivo do site (criar um repositório de conhecimento sobre programação), as respostas devem servir não só para quem perguntou, mas para **qualquer visitante futuro**. Sendo assim, o fato do AP ser estudante, formado, noob, curioso ou um profissional com décadas de experiência, é irrelevante. Por fim, [código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052), e vale o que foi dito: vc escolhe se vai mostrar a abordagem mais simples ou a mais avançada, e a comunidade avalia via voto (cada caso é um caso)

Comment: A palavra que responde essa dúvida é a mencionada "contexto". Não tem como dar uma resposta simples para uma pergunta sobre um algoritmo complexo, da mesma forma que é inviável expressar um algoritmo da forma mais complicada com a solução mais fácil. Além disso, a forma que o AP/OP responde importa muito, com seu "estilo" de código. Isso acaba sendo pessoal e contextual no final.

Comment: Mas seguindo o que o @hkotsubo mencionou, é **importante ressaltar que o seu conteúdo será visto por diferentes tipos de pessoas**, então adaptar seu código para ser "o mais abrangente possível" e ao mesmo tempo "limpo" é uma boa prática na comunidade.

Comment: Eu gosto da ideia, mas **geralmente** os experientes AR, mesmo que façam de formas diferentes, fornecem exemplos claros, o problema são as respostas de suporte personalizado/pessoal de alguns ARs menos experientes ou até insistentes na "falha" em atuar no site, suas respostas costumam focar no copia e cola que funcionará. Não são poucos os casos, temos exemplos de ARs que respondem muitas perguntas por dia que suas respostas se baseiam nisso. A postagem aqui no META é interessante, mas penso que ela nem precisaria ser uma pergunta, mas sim um "vamos fazer!".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ela é um direcionamento e um quanto uma mobilização. É legal também pontuar isso. Acredito que "copia e cola" não faz parte das nossas diretrizes de qualidade e temos que remover esse conteúdo, o que já estamos fazendo aliás. Os usuários bons dão boas respostas e fazem boas perguntas. Os outros sequer sabem que o meta existe, e os que sabem não tão nem aí. Nesse escopo, acho que cabe ter uma outra discussão e outra mobilização, talvez usando este conteúdo como "anexo".

Comment: Sim eu notei o intuito, mas o que digo é que deveria ser já evidente, porque me parece a postagem me parece uma boa ideia, seria algo no estilo de *Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas*, já sendo bem direto, pois é um assunto bastante discutido em paralelo (chats) e quem está bem alinhado com o site provavelmente já entende a importância, então tem momentos que não precisamos ser indiretos, quem se importa com o site vai compreender e provavelmente concordar com a proposta, por isso creio que podemos ser mais diretos e objetivos :) ... ps: editei meu comentário anterior.

Comment: Para resumir, estive pensando que algo um pouco mais "intuitivo" teria um resultado melhor sobre a comunidade. Temos um acervo gigantesco de tutoriais e materiais para alcançarmos uma qualidade superior à que temos hoje, mas o resultado é decepcionante como conhecemos. Proponho que se dirigirmos uma informação de forma mais simples, intuitiva e prática alcançaria resultados melhores do que já temos hoje. Guias, manuais ou postagens não vão servir para usuários que não estejam interessados em ler "guias".

Comment: Talvez um vídeo seria de bom agrado para a comunidade, para ensinar o pessoal que é "preguiçoso em ler". A comunidade não é feita para pessoas que não se interessam em ler documentações, mas acredito que está difícil para elas se adaptarem às diretrizes do SOpt, e, portanto, é mais fácil adaptarmos-vos às nossas diretrizes de forma que seria mais fácil a eles.

Comment: É perceptível também que a maioria do público que publica conteúdo de baixa qualidade não é profissional. Não exercem atividade profissional ou não tiveram esse tipo de contato ainda. Não o suficiente para se adaptarem a comunidade.